# How to make a HTTPS call from inside a Rails controller

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to access the Facebook graph api as follows:

```
$request_content = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/$request_id?$app_token"), TRUE);
```

How can I do this inside a Rails controller?

(The above is from php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require 'net/http'
fb = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/#{request_id}?#{app_token}")).body
request_content = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(fb)
```

Comment: Hi Xarem I tried the code as stated above and I get this error: bad URI(is not URI?). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you URL Encoded your Parameters? Try URI.parse(URI.encode("http://...")). URL contains probably special characters like umlauts.

Comment: As this is a call to HTTPS don't I need to use 'net/https' ?

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but try something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
request_content = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/#{request_id}?#{app_token}")).body
```